# Android click a button by intent

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a service running into my device. When this service execute a specific task, i want to create an intent. This intent should open another application and at the same time, perform a button click that is implemented in this second app. How do I SEND and GET this intent?

This is the manifest of the second application.

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.app2">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I don't know how to implement the sender. Is this correct?:

```
Intent in = new Intent("com.example.app2.MAIN");
context.startService(in);
```

Comment: you want to start another activity or another application?

Comment: you can start another activity of another app by using action-filter, where the activity on the second app declares (in manifest) that it have action_XXX, and in your intent (1st app)  you ask to perform action_XXX so that activity got started (by the OS) check this http://hmkcode.com/android-start-another-activity-of-another-application/

Answer (score 0):

I solved implemented a simply intent a put Extra:

```
Intent ii = new Intent();
ii.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.app2", "com.example.app2.INTENT_MAIN"));
ii.putExtra("ACTION", "TEST");
this.startService(ii);
```

and into the second activity, I read the intent extra value:

```
 Intent ii = new Intent();
 ii.getStringExtra("ACTION");
```